# Controls disappear in Firefox and no audio or video

Tags: mediaelement.js

Here's the code I'm using, which works perfectly on Chrome, and Safari, but not in Firefox.

This is the website the audio file is on: http://missioninstitute.org/testimonies-of-transformation/

In Firefox it shows the audio player, but as soon as you click on the play button it disappears off the page and the sound does not begins.

I've also found a similar problem with video, although for me the video box doesn't disappear (it's using a DivX player in firefox), instead when you click on the play button it just says "Buffering 0%" forever.

Here's the video code I'm using.

I'm not proficient with CSS or JS, I'm pretty new to this type of thing. In fact, in the case of video, I had to copy this code from some other website and replace the URLs to make video work on my website. Simple answers would be easiest for me to understand.

Can someone tell me how to make this work on firefox? Also, I don't have access to IE, could someone check to make sure it works OK on IE that would be great too.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FireFox the audio file wont support **.mp3** file.. so you have to convert it into **.ogg** file and embed it .. then it will play...  and read this article too..
:: **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements**